# Clojure , how to pass correct param into function

Tags: clojure

I'm newbee in Clojure world. My pet project is writing of kafka consumer / producer. There a lot of topic in www ,but I've faced with misunderstanding.

There is a code

```
(ns producer
  (:require [clojure.tools.logging :as log])
  (:import  (java.util Properties)
            (org.apache.kafka.common.serialization StringSerializer)
            (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer KafkaProducer ProducerRecord))
  (:gen-class))

(defn create-kafka-producer [server]
    (let [producer-props {
        "value.serializer" StringSerializer
        "key.serializer" StringSerializer
        "bootstrap.servers" server }]

        (KafkaProducer. producer-props)))

(defn send-single-message [producer topic-name record]
    (.send producer (ProducerRecord. topic-name (str "Value: " (.value record)))))

(defn -main []
    (def svr "localhost:8084")
    (def producer (create-kafka-producer svr))
    (send-single-message producer "Test msg"))
```

I want just pass some msg into kafka through `send-single-message` function. But as you see in code example is using (.value record) and when I'm trying to pass the "Test msg" string it crashed and show the followed error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching field found: value for class java.lang.String
```

I understand that is because I've pass string object, that has no `.value`
So, how is it possible to solve that issue? Thanks in advance
p.s. I've tried to pass other structure, but no results or different errors

Comment: And in your main, don't use `def`. Use `let` like everywhere else. Not your problem here, just a pet peeve. `def` creates unscoped globals.

Comment: Hm, I've tried and it works. I've followed the manual. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, the error is because you're attempting to get the `value` field of the passed object, but you're passing in a String which doesn't have a `value` field.

Checking that `ProducerRecord` constructor signature, it takes a generic argument of type `V` (which is just an `Object` as far as Clojure is concerned). I'd just pass the String directly and omit the `value` field access.